# How to use hex as hex values in Java

Tags: java, integer

#### Problem

I wanted to perform bit operation with Java and was expecting the same behavior that happens with C or C++. However it is not working as intended.

#### In C or C++

```
printf("%d", 0 > 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

this would return `0` (which is false)

#### However in Java

```
System.out.println(0 > 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

returns `true`

#### What I understand

I know how 2's complement works. The below is that I am guessing what is happening internally with those two languages.

- C++ or C just translates `0xFFFFFFFF` to `0xFFFFFFFF` itself, so value `0` is smaller than `0xFFFFFFFF` thus resulting `false`.
- Java translates `0xFFFFFFFF` with 2's complement as `-1`, so value `0` is bigger than `-1` thus resulting `true`.

#### Question

Is there any possible way that Java can work just like C++ or C did? **I would like Java's hex values to be recognized as hex values instead of converting them into signed int values?**

Comment: If you want hex values, use a string. Otherwise hex doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn So you are telling me that, using hex as string and then converting that string to integer is the only way to achieve this goal?

Comment: You can use the `long` type. It is still signed, but is 64 bits. But I'm not sure *exactly* what the problem is? Signed or unsigned, you have 32bits which will behave predictably. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `0xFFFFFFFF` is probably just an unsigned int in C++. In Java it's an `int`. In Java `int` is signed. If you want to treat it as unsigned, use the different `Integer.*unsigned` methods. But this has **NOTHING** to do with hex. Hexadecimal is a way to represent an integer as string.

Comment: @tgdavies The question that I wanted to ask was that "is there any possible way of Java recognizing hex values as unsigned values?"

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I understand Hex is just a way of representing a integer. However what I was curious about was that if it was possible to just let hex values be understood as unsigned integer or long values.

Comment: If you use 32 bit `long` hex literals, they will behave like 32 bit unsigned numbers to some extent, e.g. `long l = 0xFFFFFFFFL; System.out.println(l);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java the literal `0xFFFFFFFF` represents the `int` whose value is -1.  In Java `int` is a signed type.

In C / C++ `0xFFFFFFFF` will typically be **either** a `long` **or** an `unsigned long`.  In the former case, it represents -1.  In the latter case it represents 2^32 - 1 ... a very large positive integer.

---

> Is there any possible way that Java can work just like C++ or C did?

No.

> I would like Java's hex values to be recognized as hex values instead of converting them into signed int values?

Well the problem is that Java `int` is signed.  And you can't change that.

However, there are methods in the `Integer` class that will treat an `int` value *as if* it was unsigned; e.g. `Integer.compareUnsigned`, `divideUnsigned` and `parseUnsignedInt`.  See the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) for more details.

Comment: I was replying to those people in the original post so couldn't see this answer yet. So short answer no, I now clearly understand that Java takes `int` as signed.